# How to find records by comma separated ids=1,2,3 in query params using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to find records by id(s), id may be one or more in query params with comma separated values same as `https://example.com/records/get?ids=1,2,3`. ids may contain zero like `ids=1,2,0,3` or may be `ids=1,`.

```
const getRecords = async (req, res) => {
  const { ids } = req.query; // ids = 1,3,4, etc.
  const result = await Model.findAll({
     where: {
       id: {
         [Op.in]: ids
       }
     }
  });
  console.log(result);
  return res.send(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
const getRecords = async (req, res) => {
  const { ids } = req.query; // ids = 1,3,4, etc.
  let searchStr = {};
  if(ids && ids != undefined && ids != '') {
      const splitIds = await ids.toString().split(',');
      searchStr.id = {
         [Op.in]: splitIds.map(Number).filter(elem => elem > 0)
      }
  }
  const result = await Model.findAll({
     where: searchStr
  });
  console.log(result);
  return res.send(result);
}
```

Hope this help.